# Set default values for the SharedPreferences for the whole aplication

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I have the **application** with coding key, that should be visible from all parts of the application. It has to have a default value and an ability to be changed from one of the activities. How can I set this default value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SharedPrefrences in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442592/sharedprefrences-in-android)

Comment: try to do google before asking on stackover flow

Comment: I have googled it and it did`t help.

Comment: your question is not clear . ask with proper explaination

Comment: @ArthurArthur see my comment above, while getting value from sharedPrefrences try `String username = prefs.getString("username", defaultValue);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: Please, learn how to google. Keywords: `android shared preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

To save default value you have **Two** options **.
1. SharedPreference** 
**2. Database.**

Try with **SharedPreference**

Create Helper class.

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "SharedPreferencesHelper";
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public SharedPreferencesHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("loginDetails",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * To set login details
     * @param userName : username to set
     * @param password : password to set
     */
    public void setLoginDetails(String userName, String password) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("userName",userName);
        editor.putString("password",password);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * To check and get login details
     * @param userName : name to validate
     * @param password : password to validate
     * @return true : if valid user
     *         false : if valid password
     */
    public boolean isValidUser(String userName, String password) {
        // to get username
        Log.d(TAG, "username = " + sharedPreferences.getString("userName", null));
        Log.d(TAG, "password = " + sharedPreferences.getString("password", null));

        if(sharedPreferences.getString("userName",null).equals(userName) && sharedPreferences.getString("password",null).equals(password))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

To access from any where in application (activity / fragment)

```
SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPreferencesHelper = new SharedPreferencesHelper(this);
sharedPreferencesHelper.setLoginDetails("admin","admin");
sharedPreferencesHelper.isValidUser("admin","admin");
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
```

you can set the default value like this:

```
String username = sharedPreferences.getString("USER_NAME", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
```